# Based on a sample of size $n$, find a sufficient and complete statistics for $\theta$ and the MLE for $\theta$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, ...., X_n$ be iid random variables from the following distribution

| $x$ | $-1$ | $0$ | $1$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P(X=x)$ | $\theta / 3$ | $(1- \theta)$ | $2\theta/3$ |

for $0\leq \theta \leq 1$.

Based on a sample of size $n$, find

(a) suficient and complete statistics for $\theta$.

(b) MLE for $\theta$

My try:

We got that

$\prod^n_{i}f(x_i;\theta)=\prod^n_{x_i=-1}\theta/3\prod^n_{x_i=-1}(1-\theta)\prod^n_{x_i=-1}2\theta/3=L(\theta)$

for b)
I know that I have to find the máximum of the function $L(\theta)$ but I'm not sure how to do this with these discrete random variables. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Don't worry. Your comment gives me a good idea of what to do now. Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, I just realized my notation is wrong. It should instead be 
$$L(\theta) = \left(\dfrac{\theta}{3} \right)^{\sum_{i = 1}^{s}x_i}(1-\theta)^{\sum_{j=s+1}^{t-s}x_j}\left(\dfrac{2\theta}{3} \right)^{\sum_{k=t-s+1}^{n}x_k}\text{.}$$
where we assume that $x_1$ through $x_s$ are equal to $-1$, $x_{s+1}$ through $x_{t-s}$ are equal to $0$, and the remaining are equal to $1$.

Comment: (You could be a lot more picky and throw in general index sets... but I'm not going to go there.)

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216935/321264.