# Find the sufficient statistic for a mixed distribution

Tags: statistics, bayesian

Suppose that an observation $x \in (-1,1)$  comes from a sample model with a parameter $\theta$, with density function:

$$
f(x\mid\theta) = \begin{cases}
 \theta\ &\text{if}& -1 < x < 0\\
      1 - \theta\ &\text{if}& \ 0 \leqslant x < 1
\end{cases}\
$$

Consider the decision rule $δ_0(x) = (1 − x)/2$ and the quadratic loss function $L(\theta , d) = (\theta - d)^2$.

Suppose that the prior distribution for $\theta$ is uniform over the interval $(0,1)$.

a) Find the sufficient statistic of $\theta$.

b) Using the Rao-Blackwell Theorem, find a decision rule that dominates $δ_0$, which is $E(δ_0(X) \mid T=t)$

For part a), I was trying to factorize $f(x\mid\theta)$ using the indicator function but couldn't get anything. Could someone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: For a sufficient statistic, you need to write down the likelihood function in a convenient way, as shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216935/321264. This is not a 'mixed' distribution though.

Comment: Here is what I got so far: $f(x\mid\theta) = \theta^I_(-1,0) (1-\theta)^I_(0,1)$ so does it mean the sufficient statistic is $I_(-1,0)$ or both?

Comment: Note $I_{(-1,0)}(x)+I_{[0,1)}(x)=1$.

Comment: Okay which means I can find a decision rule using: $E(δ_0(X)∣I(−1,0)(x)=t)$ ? But here it's the part where I'm struggling. How can I do to find this expected value?