# How do I find the mass function of this zero-inflated Poisson distribution and show the given statistic is sufficent?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, sufficient-statistics

For $\theta \in [0, 1]$, $\lambda > 0$, I have the zero-inflated Poisson distribution

$$f_{\theta,\lambda}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \theta+(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda} & x=0 \\
      (1-\theta) \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}& x=1,2,…
   \end{cases}
$$

For $X_1, …, X_n$ i.i.d. observations from this distribution, I want to show that the statistic $T=(n_0,S)$ is sufficient where $n_0=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=0\}}$, $S=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

To do this, I want to show that $f_X(x | \theta,\lambda)=\Pi_{i=1}^n f_{X_i}(x_i | \theta,\lambda)$ depends on $x=(x_1,…,x_n)$ only through $n_0$ and $S$.

This is where I am having trouble, I am not sure how to calculate $f$ for this distribution - I’m not sure what the best way to handle these piecewise-given distributions would be.

Here is what I have attempted:

\begin{align*}
f_X(x | \theta,\lambda)&=\Pi_{i=1}^n f_{X_i}(x_i | \theta,\lambda) \\
&=\Pi_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=0\}} (\theta+(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda})+ (1-\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=0\}})(1-\theta) \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}) \\
&= \Pi_{i=1}^n \left(\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=0\}}(\theta+(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}(1-\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}))+(1-\theta)\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \right)\\
\end{align*}

This can then be expanded out but it becomes really messy and I cannot see any link to either $n_0$ or $S$. What should I do?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216935/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form of the joint distribution is not very convenient for identifying a sufficient statistic.

Given the data $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, write the likelihood function as

$$
L(\theta,\lambda)=\prod_{i:x_i=0}\left\{\theta+(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}\right\}\prod_{i:x_i>0}\left\{(1-\theta)\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right\}
$$

Or,

$$
L(\theta,\lambda)\propto \left(\theta+(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}\right)^{n_0}\left\{(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}\right\}^{n-n_0}\lambda^S\,,
$$

where $n_0=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf1_{\{x_i=0\}}$ is the number of zeros in the sample and $$S=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mathbf1_{\{x_i>0\}}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

That is,

$$
L(\theta,\lambda)\propto \left\{(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}\right\}^n\left(\frac{\theta+(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}}{(1-\theta)e^{-\lambda}}\right)^{n_0}\lambda^S
$$

This shows that a sufficient statistic is $T=(n_0,S)$.